# Wall collision detection, clitches though walls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm doing an app in React/html5/canvas. In the canvas, you as the user can move around in different rooms with mouseclicks. That works, and I have made the collision detection for all the walls for the rooms (the view is 2d like a RTS game).

Now to the problem: When I hit a wall I set `user.collision = true;` And the next mouseclick will set `user.collision = false;`and this will make my character move again. Problem is that I now can clip through walls if I click some more times (it clitches through).

Have thought about the logical around this and I can't figure it out, and my research did not help me.

Here is my collision detection function: (All the walls are in the `this.props.data`)

```
collision: function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.data.length; i++){
    if (user.posX > this.props.data[i].x2 && user.posX < this.props.data[i].x1 &&
        user.posY < this.props.data[i].y2 && user.posY > this.props.data[i].y1){
        user.collision = true;
     }
    }
},
```

Here is my handleMouseClick function:

```
handleMouseClick: function(event){

var rect = game.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseClick.y = event.nativeEvent.clientY - rect.top;
        mouseClick.x = event.nativeEvent.clientX - rect.left;
        distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseClick.x - user.posX, 2) + Math.pow(mouseClick.y - user.posY,2));
        user.directionX = (mouseClick.x - user.posX) / distance;
        user.directionY = (mouseClick.y - user.posY) / distance;
    if (user.collision = true){
        user.collision = false;
  }
},
```

Here is my update function:

```
update: function(){
    context.canvas.height);
        if (!user.collision){
        if(user.moving === true){
            user.posX += user.directionX * user.speed * elapsed;
            user.posY += user.directionY * user.speed * elapsed;
            this.collision();
            if(user.posX >= mouseClick.x -5 && user.posX <= mouseClick.x + 5 && user.posY >= mouseClick.y -5 && user.posY <= mouseClick.y + 5){
                user.moving = false;
            }
        }
        }
        this.drawUser();
        this.drawWalls();
    },
```

Comment: Unless you post `React` code I would recommend removing the `React` tag - this seems like a pure JS logic issue right now.

Comment: There are some React code in my code snippets, and all this code are inside my <App /> class.

Comment: How about showing us what `drawUser` and `drawWalls` do

Comment: Matthew Herbst: How about either write something that actually have something to do with problem or stop commenting on stuff that has nothing to do with the problem? @markE Thanks, will check that up and see if it helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just reverting to the previous pos if the collision test fails ?

```
update: function(){
    context.canvas.height);
    var prevPosX = user.posX;
    var prevPosY = user.posY;
    if (!user.collision){
        if(user.moving === true){
            user.posX += user.directionX * user.speed * elapsed;
            user.posY += user.directionY * user.speed * elapsed;
            this.collision();
            if( user.collision ) { // ooops !
                user.posX = prevPosX;
                user.posY = prevPosY;                
            }
            if(user.posX >= mouseClick.x -5 && user.posX <= mouseClick.x + 5 && user.posY >= mouseClick.y -5 && user.posY <= mouseClick.y + 5){
                user.moving = false;
            }
        }
    }
    this.drawUser();
    this.drawWalls();
},
```

NB: typo here

```
if (user.collision = true){
```

Comment: But if the user is fast enough the glicht will still happen (when the user passes the wall in one timestep) @Modig

Comment: @t.niese, yes, depending on game parameters (max speed and block size) a glitch can be possible or not. But a fix independant of parameters would be a lot more complex.